# how to set .__name__ in python?

Tags: python, attributes

I am trying to solve this exercise:

> Return a function that represents the polynomial with these
>   coefficients.
>
> For example, if `coefs=(10, 20, 30)`, return the function of `x` that computes
>   `30 * x**2 + 20 * x + 10`.  Also store the coefs on the `.coefs` attribute of
>    the function, and the str of the formula on the `.__name__` attribute.

This is my solution:

```
def poly(coefs):
    #write the string name
    l=len(coefs)
    coefs=reversed(coefs)
    j=0
    name=""
    for i in coefs:
        if j<l-2:
            name=name+str(i)+" * x**"+str(l-j-1)+" + "
        elif j==l-2:
            name=name+str(i)+" * x + "
        else:
            name=name+str(i)
        j=j+1
    def calc(x):
        name.replace("x",str(x))
        calc.__name__=name
        return eval(name)



    return calc
```

It does not work very well.

```
>>> p=poly((1,2,3))
>>> p
<function calc at 0x3b99938> #the name of p is not what I want!!! (*)
>>> y=p(3)
>>> p
<function 3 * x**2 + 2 * x + 1 at 0x3b99938> # now this is right!
>>>
```

How can I have the right name also in the first call (*) ?

Comment: Your posted code is incomplete; it'll throw a `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name' referenced before assignment` exception. Where is the `name = ''` initial value?

Comment: Do you need your function to be able to handle polynomials of any order, or just quadratic functions? If the latter, you could simplify things a bunch by simply requiring that `coefs` always be length 3 (and raising an exception if it is not). If the former, you'll want to generalize things even further than you do now, so that you can handle cubic or higher degree polynomials.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I make a mystake during the copy-paste now you have the complete code.

Comment: @Blckknght I must handle polynomials of any order

Comment: Oh, I was misreading your `if` statements and thought it only handled quadratics. You can still simplify your name calculation logic though, to: `name = '+'.join('{}*x**{}'.format(coef, exp) for exp, coef in enumerate(reversed(coefs)))`. It will list the terms in reverse order and include `**1` and `*x**0` on the lowest-order terms, but those are mathematically harmless. If you want them in the regular order, you can wrap the `enumerate` call in `reversed(list(...))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the name *outside* of the function object:

```
def calc(x):
    newname = name.replace("x", str(x))
    calc.__name__ = newname
    return eval(name)

calc.__name__ = name
return calc
```

Note that `str.replace()` does not replace values in strings in-place. It returns the altered string, string values themselves are immutable.

Your initial name will have to use `x`, since the value of `x` is not known at the time you call `poly()`. I'd leave *out* filling in of `x` in the name however; the function will not return that exact calculation the next time you call it with a different `x`. *Without* replacing `x` in the name each time you call the function, `calc()` would simply be:

```
def calc(x):
    return eval(name)
```

Together with adding `name = ''` at the *top* of your `poly()` function, with the namechange per call in place still, gives:

```
>>> p = poly((1,2,3))
>>> p
<function 3 * x**2 + 2 * x + 1 at 0x10ecf5488>
>>> p(3)
34
>>> p
<function 3 * 3**2 + 2 * 3 + 1 at 0x10ecf5488>
```